# Dynamic non-local exits in Common Lisp

Tags: dynamic, common-lisp, exit

According to the [*Dynamic Non-Local Exits*](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node96.html#SECTION0011110000000000000000) section of **Common Lisp the Language, 2nd Edition**,

> Intervening exits are abandoned as soon as the transfer of control is initiated; in the case of a throw, this occurs at the beginning of the "second pass" mentioned in the implementation note. It is an error to attempt a transfer of control to an exit whose dynamic extent has ended.

In SBCL `1.3.4`, however:

```cl
(catch 'a
  (catch 'b
    (unwind-protect
         (throw 'a "returning from protected")
      (throw 'b "returning from unwind"))))
;; => "returning from unwind"
```

This seems incorrect. Shouldn't exit point `'b` should be disestablished between executing the protected and  cleanup forms, thereby making the above illegal? The boat-rowing example on the same page suggests the same.

SBCL's behavior instead seems to correspond to the alternative proposal:

> ...the abandoning of exits should be lumped in with the evaluation of `unwind-protect` cleanup clauses and the undoing of dynamic bindings and catch tags, performing all in reverse order of establishment.

Is this just a matter of CLtL2 differing from the final spec?

Comment: Notice that SBCL is an implementation of ANSI Common Lisp, not CLtL2. The [hyperspec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/05_b.htm) says that the consequences of attempting to transfer control to an exit point whose dynamic extent has ended are undefined (ie doesn't have to be an error).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explained by  jkiiski, the behaviour is undefined in ANSI Common Lisp. The example is cited in the [`UNWIND-PROTECT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_unwind.htm) section in CLHS:

```
;;; The following has undefined consequences because the catch of B is 
;;; passed over by the first THROW, hence portable programs must assume 
;;; its dynamic extent is terminated.  The binding of the catch tag is not
;;; yet disestablished and therefore it is the target of the second throw.
 (catch 'a
   (catch 'b
     (unwind-protect (throw 'a 1)
       (throw 'b 2))))
```

Comment: Ah, should've checked the examples myself. Thanks!